# How to get Zencoding to add a closing comment to divs in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I had previously managed to get Zencoding in ST2 to autocomment closing tags eg:

I'd type div.my_div and hit tab and as well as creating the div, it would also add a closing comment so that I can easily navigate the closing div tags in my document.

```
<div class="my_div">
    *
</div> <!-- .my_div -->
```

Do any of you know how to replicate this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use “comment“ filter: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Filters

```
.my_tag|c
```

You can also make ZC to automatically apply “comments” filter to HTML. It‘s a bit hacky, but you need to open **zen_settings.py** file and add `c` filter at https://github.com/sublimator/ZenCoding/blob/master/zencoding/zen_settings.py#L511

It should look like this:

```
"filters": "html,c"
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey! That's exactly what I had forgotten. I had previously managed to fiddle with it a bit more, I think to remove the opening comment and to have the closing comment on the same line as the closing div but this is still great. Thank you.

Comment: Just to add that I figured out that to change the way the comment filter works you have to edit the comment.py file within the filters folder, lines 29-30.

Comment: The new plugin with upcoming v0.8 release will feature easier output comment (and many other features) modification with _user preferences_ so you don’t need to modify original source code.