# Sublime text plugin that automatically add comments to closing divs

Tags: html, sublimetext2, emmet

Is there a Sublime Text plugin that adds comments to closing div tags noting the classes or ids of that div?

Example:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Going back to Houston, do the hotdog dance</p>
</div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

I've seen code snippets where this can be done with [emmet filters](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14992) and I've also seen people suggest [HTMLAttributes](https://github.com/agibsonsw/HTMLAttributes) on GitHub.

Thanks in advance.

I had issues getting readable code in the comments below. If you paste this into Emmet.sublime.settings:

```js
{
 // Emmet preferences
 // List of all available preferences:
 // http://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/
 "preferences": {
     "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- <%= attr(\"id\", \"/#\") %> <%= attr(\"class\", \"/.\") %> -->"
 }

}
```

It will output this

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

When you type this in Emmet and hit tab:

```html
.wrapper|c
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using Emmet or HTMLAttributes?

Comment: Is the following posting answering your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829901/how-to-get-zencoding-to-add-a-closing-comment-to-divs-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1

Comment: @MattDMo - I couldn't get HTMLAttributes to work, but I did get Emmet working. If I type: 
    <code>.wrapper|c</code>
and hit Tab it will output: 
    <code><div class="wrapper"></div><!-- /.wrapper --></code>

Comment: @StefanGruenwald - The answer you linked to accomplished exactly what I wanted to. It looks like Zen Coding was/is being replaced by Emmet and appears to have the same syntax.